# What is the relation between Kruskal tensor and CP decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

In Matlab Tensor Toolbox there is a tensor type called "Kruskal tensors", I found its form is similar to the CP decomposition.

Wikipedia mentioned "[As such, many of the methods have been independently invented several times, often with subtle variations, leading to a confusing literature. Abstract and general mathematical theorems are rare (though see Kruskal[1] with regard to the CP decomposition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition)"

In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.1796.pdf) on [*A concise proof of Kruskal's theorem on tensor decomposition*]， it mentioned "...In these
fields, the expression of a tensor as a sum of rank-1 tensors is often referred to as the
Candecomp or Parafac decomposition."

**So, what is the relation or difference between Kruskal tensor decomposition and [CP decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_decomposition)?**

**Are they actually the same thing but Kruskal decomposition is devised by a different person in different field for 3-dimensional tensor?**

Answer (score 4):

Tensor Toolbox stores the output of a CP - Decomposition as a kruskal Tensor.
The output format of a Kruskal Tensor is [ Lambda; A, B , C ] , where one element of Lambda is the value that is obtained when a particular Column of A, B, C is normalized. Let lambda ai be value obtained by normalizing ith column of A and so on. Therefore Lambda i = lambda ai * lambda bi * lambda ci. ( My guess )

Therefore Lambda is a vector of size R. 
A particular column of A is in a outer product with the corresponding column of B, C, (**a**i o **b**i o **c**i), this outer product is multiplied by **Lambda** i to give a rank 1 tensor, this format of writing a tensor is known as kruskal tensor. 
For more details refer to :